# How to set the height of a flex box without setting its position to absolute?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to assign a dimension of `height: 50px` to

```
.panelDraggable__header 
.panelDraggable__info 
.panelDraggable__footer
```

Using the following code I am not able to set the height, if you trying to inspect `.panelDraggable__header` its computed value is 18px.

Only way is when I adjust the position to absolute, which disrupt my layout.

- How to solve this problem?
- What is in general the best way to add the right dimension to a flex box?
- Should I use `flex-basis` instead?

```css
#panelDevTools {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.panelDraggable {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.panelDraggable__header {
  order: 0;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 50px;
}
.panelDraggable__info {
  order: 1;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  height: 50px;
}
.panelDraggable__content {
  order: 3;
  background-color: slategrey;
}
.panelDraggable__footer {
  order: 4;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div data-ntv-type="PanelDevTools" class="panelDraggable" id="panelDevTools" widgetid="panelDevTools">
  <div id="panelDevTools__info" class="panelDraggable__info">Tools for developement</div>
  <div id="panelDevTools__content" class="panelDraggable__content">
    <div id="cnt-inner" style="height:800px;width:50px;background-color:red;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="panelDevTools__footer" class="panelDraggable__footer ">Footer</div>
  <div id="panelDevTools__header" class="panelDraggable__header">
    <div id="panelDevTools__title" class="panelDraggable__title">Developer Tools</div>
    <div id="panelDevTools__handle" class="panelDraggable__handle"></div>
    <div id="panelDevTools__help" class="panelDraggable__help"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine for me in Firefox and Chrome. I don't understand what the problem is. Only the content div is stretchable, others are fixed.

Comment: @ManojKumar I need for example have the light green div "Developer Tools" (#panelDevTools__header) of size 50px, if you inspect the code is now 18px. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, please mention in the question that the computed value is 20px. I just checked in Firebug box model.

Comment: @ManojKumar thanks for your comment, question edited.

Comment: The problem is due to the height of the parent container `#panelDevTools { height: 300px; }` I am not sure why is it set there.

Comment: I think you only want to set the height to 50px. To do that simply set the style of `.panelDraggable__header  .panelDraggable__info  
.panelDraggable__footer`  to `display: table; width: 100%;`

Comment: @Guru unfortunately using display: table; seems that does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use min-height instead of height as you actually what the height to be flexible but at least 50px

```css
#panelDevTools {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.panelDraggable {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.panelDraggable__header {
  order: 0;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.panelDraggable__info {
  order: 1;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.panelDraggable__content {
  order: 3;
  background-color: slategrey;
}
.panelDraggable__footer {
  order: 4;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div data-ntv-type="PanelDevTools" class="panelDraggable" id="panelDevTools" widgetid="panelDevTools">
  <div id="panelDevTools__info" class="panelDraggable__info">Tools for developement</div>
  <div id="panelDevTools__content" class="panelDraggable__content">
    <div id="cnt-inner" style="height:800px;width:50px;background-color:red;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="panelDevTools__footer" class="panelDraggable__footer ">Footer</div>
  <div id="panelDevTools__header" class="panelDraggable__header">
    <div id="panelDevTools__title" class="panelDraggable__title">Developer Tools</div>
    <div id="panelDevTools__handle" class="panelDraggable__handle"></div>
    <div id="panelDevTools__help" class="panelDraggable__help"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more why min-height instead of height, I do not get why height is not being considered and min-height yes. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: by setting display:flex you are basically telling the browser to set width / height to auto and confirm it to the content, if you however what to have it at least x pixels heigh then you need to tell him that by adding a min-height witch effectively overwrites the height attribute

Comment: `height: 300px` is fixed. Boxes within this container can't grow vertically. As you noticed, a 50px height was adjusted to 18px, so it could fit within the fixed container. With `min-height: 300px` the height is flexible. It can't go lower than 300px, but can grow from there.